# Separate array items with same name

Tags: php, xml

I've been trying to figure out how to separate these items.. I'm getting a full array like this:

```
array = ('name' => 'test', 'last name' => 'test' , 'name' => 'test1');
```

But i need it this way: (Example not well typed)

```
0[('name' => 'a name', 'lastname' => 'a last name')], 1[('name' => 'a name', 'last name' => 'a last name')]
```

I only need to find one string and the last name behind that string. I can't transform the array because it's from a real big XML file.

Comment: if name and last name are always in sequence then separate every two array items

Comment: I just need one name and the last name not the rest of it. Could you provide me a quick example how i can achieve this?

Comment: `array = ('name' => 'test', 'last name' => 'test' , 'name' => 'test1');` not possible, u r using same key for two values, share the correct array

Comment: can you show the xml file from where you get that array ?

Comment: It's like this:<Accounts>
    <name>name</name>
    <last_name>a last name</last_name>
</Accounts>
<Accounts>
    <name>name</name>
    <last_name>a last name</last_name>
</Accounts>
<Accounts>
<name>name</name>
<last_name>a last name</last_name>
</Accounts>
<Accounts>
<name>name</name>
<last_name>a last name</last_name>
</Accounts>
<Accounts>
<name>name</name>
<last_name>a last name</last_name>
</Accounts>

Comment: Process each accounts separate instead of reading all name and last_name.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help guys.

I've found a real easy solution. Stupid of me!

```
$array = array($items['name'] => $items['last_name']);
```